# Uiautomatorviewer not working. It is showing lib is not supported

Tags: uiautomatorviewer

My Java version is

```
openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It is showing like this error->

-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. The program will exit.

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

Comment: This is not Java 9 (but please don't use Java 9), and having an error message / stack trace would be nice.